# Why didn't they pause Melinda May?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the last episode *Melinda* of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*,

> A team of Special-ops S.H.I.E.L.D. Agents were disabled by the Inhuman girl child presumably on the instruction of the mother within a second, thanks to awesome power of mind control.

Later, when Melinda May sneaked into the facility to rescue S.H.I.E.L.D. Agents, why didn't they do the same to Melinda May?

Answer (score 12):

The little girls powers worked by touch. She was never touched by the small girl so she was never under her influence

Comment: In the end, she was seen killing people by hand waving.

Comment: Yes. But people already under her control though. Not random people

Comment: It's foolish to assume that all agents touched her... That's also within a second.

Comment: and yet, that's exactly how they show her power working. within the flashback scenes, may flashes back to watching the girl touch the gang on the shoulders.

Comment: @phantom42 Exactly. It is shown within the episode that this is the way she gains control over people, this how she manifests her power so this is how it works. She did not touch Melinda and therefor she never gained control over her

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 The agents were in there to rescue that little girl, and from the "friendly fire" over the radio it was more like 10 seconds

Comment: @Izkata Nope. Their primary agenda was capturing or killing the Inhuman with super strength.

Comment: @Izkata BTW, why do you think that every agent would touch her even if primary goal was rescuing the girl? Map showed that agents weren't even in the same room initially.

Comment: Yes but still, "friendly fire" incident that took enough time for the girl to pass around and touch everyone. No one thought she might be the one doing everything because, as you say, they were after the superstrength inhuman and not mind controlling one

Comment: plausible theory since we don't know what happens inside: the agents go in with two objectives: secure the woman (perceived as a threat) and secure the girl (not perceived as a threat). they go in and the little girl is not being held. they go to pull her back towards a safe area, and she goes and touches everyone. done in seconds.

Comment: whatever the agent's motivation, the show explicitly shows that the girl's power is activated by touch, so this is the right answer.